# Retrieving COM Class Factory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, office-interop

I get the Error - Retrieving the COM class factory...' at the line

```
Excel.Workbook wb = new Excel.Workbook.
```

Using VS2010, Windows 7 64 bit, MS Office 2007. Already set the Target platform to 'X(86)'.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

protected void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  OpenExcel();
}

private void OpenExcel()
{
  Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
  Excel.Workbook wb = new Excel.Workbook();
  Excel.Worksheet ws = new Excel.Worksheet();
  Excel.Range range = null;

  app.visible = true;
  wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
  ws = wb.WorkSheets[1];

  range = ws.get_Range("A1","A3");
   ws.Cells[0,0]="Date";
   ws.Cells[0,1]="Code";
   ws.Cells[0,2]="Name";
}
```

Comment: just a simple question because `one cannot assume` but do you have `MS Office` Installed..?

Comment: try looking at this site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066603/opening-ms-excel-worksheet-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thank you, I guess creating instances for all the variables was causing that. Set them all to null.